# Can I match a range instead of a single value in a C++ switch statement?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I am new into programming. Is it possible to use `<`, `>` in a switch case?

For instance,

```
 ...
 ...
 ...
 int i;
 cin>> i;
 ...
 ...
 switch(i){
 case 20<i<35
 ...
```

Comment: The syntax you're thinking of would be `20 .. 35`, but that would be another language.

Answer (score 7):

C++ does not offer a `switch` syntax for matching ranges.

When ranges are relatively small, you could supply case labels, and rely on fall-through:

```
switch(i) {
    case 20:
    case 21:
    case 22:
    case 23:
    case 24:
    case 25: doSomething();
             break;
    case 26:
    case 27:
    case 28:
    case 29: doSomethingElse();
             break;
    ...
}
```

For medium-size ranges (1000 elements or so) you could use a vector of function objects to dispatch to a particular logic, but that requires a lot more work than writing a simple `switch` statement.

For large ranges your best bet is a chain of `if`-`else` statements.